# Vertical alignment with square roots and double integral

Tags: math-mode

The following double integral (latex with amsmath) has several alignment problems

```
$\ds \int_0^{1/\sqrt 2}\int_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}e^{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx\,dy$
```

The two upper bounds are not well aligned and in the exponent the factor 2 and the root are not well aligned either. (Several readers have complained that the formula is not clear and asked if the 2 signifies the square root or it is a factor in front of the root.) Is there a simple solution to align these better?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 4):

For the two upper bounds:

- You can reach proper alignment by using a `\vphantom` with the largest element of the second upper bound, so that the first upper bound is also set according to this maximum dimensions. You can either add `\vphantom{y^2}` inside the square root, to enlargen the root sign (as in mf67'2 answer); or add `\vphantom{\sqrt{y^2}}` to the upper bound outside of the root sign, to have the root sign at the same size but at the proper baseline.
- To further help the reader, you could also add a small space like `\,` between the two integrals, to make the distinction between the two upper bounds easier.

For the exponent:

- The exponent is properly aligned since the `2`, the `x` and the `y` are all set on the same baseline. So a change of vertical positions doesn't really help you here.
- My favourite alternative is to set the exponent not as an exponent, but as an "exponential function". Then, the three symbols are larger and it is more easily recognizable that they are at the same baseline.
- Another option would be to add a `\cdot` to highlight that this is indeed a product.

The MWE below shows the original situation in the first line, and the different alternatives in the other two lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^{1/\sqrt 2}\int\limits_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}e^{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^{1/\sqrt{2\vphantom{y^2}}}\,\int\limits_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\exp\left(2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$

$\displaystyle \int\limits_0^{1/\sqrt 2\vphantom{\sqrt{y^2}}}\,\int\limits_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}e^{2\cdot\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My positive vote there is. You can add, if you want, also the example `e^{2(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}}` to have 2 baseline with `\sqrt`. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution;

```
\[\int\limits_0^{1/\sqrt{2\vphantom{y^2}}}\;\int\limits_y^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}e^{2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx\,dy\]
```

[image]